# solr: string field does not yield partial match result using qf parameter

Tags: solr, solr4, dismax

My experience is opposite of http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/string-field-does-not-yield-exact-match-result-using-qf-parameter-td4060096.html

When I add 'qf' to to dismax query I get no result unless there's a full match.

I am using NGramFilterFactory as follows:

```
 <fieldType name="text_edgengrams" class="solr.TextField">
   <analyzer type="index">
     <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15"/>
   </analyzer>
   <analyzer type="query">
     <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>

 ...


 <field name="text_ngrams" type="text_edgengrams" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

 ...

 <field name="domain" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

 ...

 <copyField source="domain" dest="text_ngrams"/>
```

If I have yengas.com in indexed I can search for yengas.com but not yengas. However, If I drop 'qf' I can search for yengas.

Example searches:

```
 $ curl "http://localhost:8282/solr/links/select?q=domain:yengas&wt=json&indent=on&fl=id,domain,score"
 => "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]


 $ curl "http://localhost:8282/solr/links/select?q=domain:yengas.com&wt=json&indent=on&fl=id,domain,score"
 => "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[]

 $ curl "http://localhost:8282/solr/links/select?defType=dismax&q=yengas&qf=domain^4&pf=domain&ps=0&fl=id,domain,score"
 => "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]


 $ curl "http://localhost:8282/solr/links/select?defType=dismax&q=yengas.com&pf=domain&ps=0&fl=id,domain,score"
 => "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[]
```

The partial match fails on dismax and normal query.

What could I be missing?

Comment: It looks like partial match doesn't work with original field but with copied to field. This works `$ curl "http://localhost:8282/solr/links/select?q=text_ngrams:yengas&wt=json&indent=on&fl=id,domain,score"`

Answer (score 0):

CopyField does not change the Original Field.
As well the Copyfield does not apply the Original analysis to the Copied field.

Documentation @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields

> The copy is done at the stream source level and no copy feeds into another copy.

Having a copyfield as the source of copyfield tag does not work.
The copyfield source must be an actual field, which has some value and does no cascade.

So the Original and Copied Field would behave as per the definition, which in your case are String and ngrams.